# Type traits to detect if a callable has side effects?

Tags: c++, function, c++14, template-meta-programming, side-effects

My question is simple to ask, but I guess, difficult to answer.

In C++14, is there a way to test if a callable (function, function member, lambda function, std::function etc...) has a side effect or not?

If so, how would a type traits:

```
template <class T>
struct has_side_effects;
```

would be like?

I am ok with a trait that would return false positive (says that a function has side effects while it does not), but not ok with a trait that would return false negative (says that a function has no side effects while it does).

For example, I would like the trait:

```
auto comparator = [](const auto& x, const auto& y){return y > x;};
bool result = std::has_side_effects<decltype(comparator)>::value;
```

to return `false`.

Comment: That's impossible unless the function is constexpr

Comment: static analyzer may help... but it seems not a trivial task.

Comment: @DieterLücking it's not possible for `constexpr` either, unless is guaranteed by the implementer. `constexpr` functions are allowed to have branches that lead to side effects.

Comment: This seems like it could reduce to the halting problem, could it not?

Comment: @erip: It would only reduce to the halting problem if no false positives were allowed.  Otherwise, as stated by Yakk, there is a trivial algorithm that simply says "everything has side effects" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated, `template<class T> using has_side_effects = std::true_type;` solves most of your problem.  Simply state that everything has side effects, and ship it.  False positives, but no false negatives!

In general, non-trivial properties of an algorithm coded in a Turing-complete system cannot be computed.  Doing so is equivalent to the halting problem.  So the problem cannot be solved in general.

In specific cases, C++ offers basically zero reflection over the contents of an algorithm.  At best it offers some reflection over the *interface* of an algorithm, but the interface of an algorithm/function does not contain information about the purity of the algorithm.

The closest you can get is "can it be invoked within a `constexpr` context".

In a concrete case:

```
auto comparator = [](const auto& x, const auto& y){return y > x;};
bool result = std::has_side_effects<decltype(comparator)>::value;
```

result would have to be `true`, as:

```
struct evil {
  static int count() { static int r = 0; return ++r; }
  friend bool operator<( evil lhs, evil rhs ) { count(); return false; }
};
```

then `comparator(evil{}, evil{})` has a side effect.  Having it return `false` when passed `comparator` is simply incorrect.

Comment: _In general, non-trivial properties of an algorithm coded in a Turing-complete system cannot be computed._ For those interested, this is Rice's Theorem.

Comment: @erip to be fair Rice's Theorem is about the language accepted by a Turing machine.  You can actually deal with non-trivial properties of the computation itself (say, "will it accept in less than a million steps?").  It takes a bit to translate "has side effects" into "property of an accept language": you reencode your abstract machine to write "X" on a tape when it does a side effect, then a language that accepts a string with a list of Xs iff the string fed to the original algorithm outputs that many Xs.

Comment: Indeed it is. I was trying to come up with some reductions and it was _hard_.